# How to define variable in class out of class and use it in IF statement

Tags: python, oop, if-statement

Everyone hello. I have learning Python for 2 months, and now I am learning OOP. And I have a question:

```
class Test():
x = 0

def __init__(self):

    if Test.x == 5:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("ERROR")
        
i = Test()
i.x = 5
```

And this is output:

```
ERROR
```

Why this code returns me an "ERROR", if x = 5? In my opinion it may return me an "OK"

Comment: `x` is not 5 in this point, it's 0. You are setting it to 5 only after you call `__init__`.

Comment: Because you set `x`: 1. on the instance not the class; and 2. _after_ `__init__` runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your `Test` class x in 0 so you get the ERROR output
what you want to do is probably something like this

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            print("OK")
        else:
             print("ERROR")
```

`i = Test(5)` prints
`OK`